# Detect duplicate keys in javascript scripts using VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

Is there a way to highlight a warning for duplicate keys when my code looks like this?

```
db.locales.insertOne({
  ...
        "advanced": {
          "t0": "Calm wind",
          "t1": "Very light breeze",
          "t2": "Light breeze",
          "t3": "Stiff breeze",
          "t4": "Light wind", <-- warning
          "t4": "Stiff wind", <-- warning
          "t6": "Cool wind",
          ...
});
```

I am using VSCode along with ESlint and Prettier

Comment: ... did you disable `javascript.validate.enable`?

Comment: @starball no and the linked question doesn't solve my problem